# Changing an xcode project Path with lowercase path issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a problem with an Xcode project which has a path of "/users/me/blah" with a lowercase 'u'. When I check my other projects (in the General Tab of the Project Info Window the Path starts with a uppercase "Users".

This causes a couple of problems. When I try and add an existing file which is "relative to group" or "Relative to Project" it thinks it needs to change directory all the way to the root. For example the path for any included file ends up as "../../../../Users/me/blah" which then prevents the project working on other peoples machine because the "relative" is essentially an absolute path... sigh.

The other side effect is that when you select "Add Existing Files" instead of greying out all of the already included files, it leaves ALL of the files available for selection. Because it thinks files in "Users" are different to "users".

I have tried re checking out the project into a different directory but no difference.

I am not sure how I ended up with the wrong path in the first instance. No doubt something stupid that I did.

Anyone have a clue on how I change the project path or resolve this?

thanks

Comment: Have you found solution for that? I tried reinstall Xcode, but it does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the blah.xcodeproj directory and open project.pbxproj in a text editor. Look for the lowercase "u" and replace it with an uppercase. While you wouldn't want to hand-write the project.pbxproj file, it's quite safe to do minor edits on it.

Comment: thx Rob, i did what u suggested and interestingly there was no reference to the lowercase "users" in that file only the "../../../../../Users"

I think I have fixed it though, if I use the "Open..." function from the xcode "File" menu rather than double clicking on the project file from Finder, xcode appears to think it comes from "Users"... weird